# AWS Glue 2.0 Pyspark failes to deletes .staging directory - MultiObjectDeleteException: One or more objects could not be deleted

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

In AWS Glue 2.0 - apache spark 2.4.3 pyspark I have very simple pyspark.DataFrame save with parquet overwrite since we have deleted data from the existing dataframe. I receive this error `com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.MultiObjectDeleteException: One or more objects could not be deleted`.

A couple notes I have seen from other questions and answers we are repartitioning, never does is this error occur because there are more than 1000 files. We have used s3a and s3 in AWS Glue both have this error but the error itself uses a different jar in which the error occurs. I believe aws glue uses EMR but not sure which version. It is not a permissions issues since this is the only AWS Glue that creates/updates/deletes from this bucket, and deletes do successfully work.

```
                (
                    df.write.mode("overwrite")
                    .format("parquet")
                    .option("compression", "snappy")
                    .option("schema", table_schema)
                    .partitionBy("date_loaded", "bundle_id")
                    .save("s3a://<bucket>/<database>/<prefix>/<table>/")
                )
```

Spark conf

```
 spark_conf = SparkConf().setAll([
        ("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic"),
        ("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy"),
        ("spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat", "true"),
        ("spark.files.maxPartitionBytes", "268435456"),
        ("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", "268435456"),
        ("spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes", "268435456"),
        ("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy"),
        ("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic"),
        ("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",
         "100")
    ])
...
spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.maxRetries", "5")
```

This is how I repartition

```
def repartition_df(df: DataFrame,
                   df_count: int = 0,
                   file_count: int = None,
                   file_size_bytes: float = None) -> DataFrame:
    """Repartition the pyspark.DataFrame, this helps reduce the time it takes
    to sort the pyspark.DataFrame when saving.

    https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/on-spark-hive-and-small-files-an-in-depth-look-at-spark-partitioning-strategies-a9a364f908#:~:text=Ideally%2C%20your%20target%20file%20size,block%20size%2C%20128MB%20by%20default.
    """
    if (file_count is not None and file_count == 1) or (file_size_bytes is not None and file_size_bytes < 2256481719.0):
        # When the incoming add/delete is small, either file count or file size repartition
        # it can be expensive when we may just be adding a file or
        # deleting a few rows - as of 2/21 the files sizes are sometimes really small
        return df
    partition_divisor = 200_000
    if 100_000_00 > df_count > 30_000_000:
        partition_divisor = 400_000
    elif df_count > 100_000_000:
        partition_divisor = 500_000
    num_partitions = math.ceil(df_count / partition_divisor)
    # logger.info(f"Coalescing to {num_partitions}")
    # df = df.coalesce(num_partitions)
    logger.info(f"Repartitioning to {num_partitions}")
    return df.repartition(num_partitions)
```

Not sure why I seem to be getting this error when this seems like a common thing people would do in AWS Glue. I run about 40 glue jobs a day so we end up getting about 4 errors per day.

Here are some stats on this error. I received the error below on the 16 table (s3 location) modification 2nd delete modification, so this error would not be expected. This is the second delete per this s3 location which is a table, so the second delete on this location in addition to the fact that we run many jobs successfully it is not a permissions issue.

Paritions:

> Repartitioning to 190

Table count and updated pyspark.DataFrame logged count

> EXISTING:39270349|NEW:37980910|EXPECTED_DELETE:884893|ACTUAL_DELETE:1289439|DIFF:-404546

Error

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
> o4627.save. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSS3IOException:
> rename(s3a://////.spark-staging-d3c13b4b-829e-4b6c-aa1f-3bb4e8bf31ea/date_loaded=2022-01-30-00-00-00/bundle_id=3dd361b2-1953-4d2a-a7ee-8b00096f7438,
> s3a://////date_loaded=2022-01-30-00-00-00/bundle_id=3dd361b2-1953-4d2a-a7ee-8b00096f7438)
> on
> s3a://////.spark-staging-d3c13b4b-829e-4b6c-aa1f-3bb4e8bf31ea/date_loaded=2022-01-30-00-00-00/bundle_id=3dd361b2-1953-4d2a-a7ee-8b00096f7438:
> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.MultiObjectDeleteException: One or
> more objects could not be deleted (Service: null; Status Code: 200;
> Error Code: null; Request ID: B3EF4WW9QF73EBSZ; S3 Extended Request
> ID:
> sEChsnpwcU92sy9aJWHLPj+QEOFDGZpYONO2Rx0TVuum3oCCqkI80rUkwByUwDBwU6Y7g/lgi60=;
> Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID:
> sEChsnpwcU92sy9aJWHLPj+QEOFDGZpYONO2Rx0TVuum3oCCqkI80rUkwByUwDBwU6Y7g/lgi60=:
> One or more objects could not be deleted (Service: null; Status Code:
> 200; Error Code: null; Request ID: B3EF4WW9QF73EBSZ; S3 Extended
> Request ID:
> sEChsnpwcU92sy9aJWHLPj+QEOFDGZpYONO2Rx0TVuum3oCCqkI80rUkwByUwDBwU6Y7g/lgi60=;
> Proxy: null)  at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:178)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:101)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.rename(S3AFileSystem.java:664)
> at
> org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol$$anonfun$commitJob$7.apply(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:200)
> at
> org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol$$anonfun$commitJob$7.apply(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:187)
> at
> scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1.foreach(HashSet.scala:316)
> at
> scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:972)
> at
> org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:187)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:187)
> ... 32 more
>
> Caused by:
> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.MultiObjectDeleteException: One or
> more objects could not be deleted (Service: null; Status Code: 200;
> Error Code: null; Request ID: B3EF4WW9QF73EBSZ; S3 Extended Request
> ID:
> sEChsnpwcU92sy9aJWHLPj+QEOFDGZpYONO2Rx0TVuum3oCCqkI80rUkwByUwDBwU6Y7g/lgi60=;
> Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID:
> sEChsnpwcU92sy9aJWHLPj+QEOFDGZpYONO2Rx0TVuum3oCCqkI80rUkwByUwDBwU6Y7g/lgi60=
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.deleteObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:2321)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.deleteObjects(S3AFileSystem.java:983)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.removeKeys(S3AFileSystem.java:1205)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerRename(S3AFileSystem.java:827)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.rename(S3AFileSystem.java:662)
> ... 38 more

How do we address this?

Comment: i'd expect that to be permissions, only place i've ever seen it. aws s3 logs might provide more details

Comment: yeah that is the direction most people say the problem occurs which is why i clarified it is not a permissions error, at least it is not in the sense of iam + bucket access

Comment: nobody understands IAM. i do know that to test s3a handling of partial deletes, we create an assumed role session without write access. never seen any other cause of it. https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-3.2/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/auth/ITestAssumeRole.java#L828

Comment: okay i am following, and aws glue does create a glue role session at the end of the day from the IAM role provided to the aws glue job. could you think of why it would be able to create these files but in the same spark job be unable to delete these files I had this occuring on the .staging directory? also would this assumed role session you linked also affect s3n?